# How to create a bunch of PDFs from the values ​of a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel, canvas

I'm developing an application to automate the issuance of service receipts, mining the internet I managed to generate the PDFs with the  `canvas` library. The code works correctly, it accesses a spreadsheet, creates lists with the data, then comes the part of the PDF issue, when it comes to that part it is my question. It only generates a single PDF, from the last client in the spreadsheet and not from everyone in the spreadsheet.

Follow the code below:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from datetime import date, datetime, timezone, timedelta
import openpyxl


# Opens the spreadsheet and obtains the status of the last payment.

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('./lib/cobranca3.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

lastCol = sheet.max_column

# Checks the payment status of each customer.

unpaidMembers = {}
codigos = []
clients = []
cnpjs = []
emails = []
vencimentos = []
valores = []
acrescimos = []
antecipacoes = []
descontos = []
months = []

for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for c in range(13, lastCol + 1):
        payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
        if payment != 'ok' or '':
            codigo = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
            cliente = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
            cnpj = sheet.cell(row=r, column=3).value
            email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=4).value
            venc = sheet.cell(row=r, column=6).value
            valor = sheet.cell(row=r, column=7).value
            acresc = sheet.cell(row=r, column=8).value
            antec = sheet.cell(row=r, column=9).value
            desc = sheet.cell(row=r, column=10).value
            month = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
            codigos.append(codigo)
            clients.append(cliente)
            cnpjs.append(cnpj)
            emails.append(email)
            vencimentos.append(venc)
            valores.append(valor)
            months.append(month)
            unpaidMembers[cliente] = email
            print('Line:', r, 'Column:', c, 'Código:', codigo, 'Client:', cliente, 'CNPJ:', cnpj, 'Email:', email, 'Vencimento:', venc, 'Valor:', (valor + acresc) - antec - desc, 'Month:', month)
            #print('dictionary created successfully')


for r in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):

    # Creating Canvas
    #c = canvas.Canvas("invoice.pdf", pagesize=A4, bottomup=0)
    c = canvas.Canvas(str(codigo) + '_' + 'PS.pdf', pagesize=A4, bottomup=0)

    data_atual = date.today()
    data_atual_formatada = '{}/{}/{}'.format(data_atual.day, data_atual.month, data_atual.year)

    # Setting the font for Name title of company
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 20)
    # Inserting the name of the company
    c.drawCentredString(295, 50, "NOTA DE SERVIÇOS PRESTADOS")

    # linha de separação
    c.line(10, 75, 580, 75)  # começa em, tem altura de, comprimento, altura

    # Setting the font
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 12)
    c.drawString(10, 110, "Código: %s" % codigo)

    c.drawString(200, 110, "Cliente: %s" % cliente)

    c.drawString(10, 140, "Data Emissão: %s" % data_atual_formatada)

    c.drawString(200, 140, "Data vencimento: %s" % month)

    # linha de separação
    c.line(10, 165, 580, 165)  # começa em, tem altura de, comprimento, altura

    c.drawString(10, 190, "Pagamento referente à:")

    # Setting the font
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 15)

    c.drawString(35, 220, "Honorário: ")
    c.drawString(120, 220, "%s" % month)

    # Setting the font
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 12)

    c.drawString(35, 250, "Valor: ")
    c.drawString(500, 250, "R$ %s" % valor)

    c.drawString(35, 280, "Acréscimo: ")
    c.drawString(500, 280, "R$ %s" % acresc)

    c.drawString(35, 310, "Antecipação: ")
    c.drawString(500, 310, "R$ %s" % antec)

    c.drawString(35, 340, "Desconto: ")
    c.drawString(500, 340, "R$ %s" % desc)

    # Setting the font
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 15)

    total = (valor + acresc) - antec - desc
    #print(total)

    c.drawString(35, 400, "TOTAL: ")
    c.drawString(500, 400, "R$ %s" % total)

    # linha de separação
    c.line(10, 425, 580, 425)  # começa em, tem altura de, comprimento, altura

    c.drawString(125, 475, "BOLETO EMITIDO PELO BANCO SANTANDER")
    c.drawString(80, 500, "Omnia Tecnologia Digital Eireli - CNPJ 10.751.327/0001-59")

    # End the Page and Start with new
    c.showPage()
    # Saving the PDF
    c.save()
```

The following worksheet is used:https://prnt.sc/13ii4ja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the canvas `c` is created from `canvas.Canvas(str(codigo), ...)` at each iteration in the for loop, but `codigo` does not change between iterations. So I think you are just overwriting one file over and over, and you only see the last PDF you created in your filesystem.

Comment: Any recomendation?

Comment: Simply change the name of your canvas: `c = canvas.Canvas(str(r) + '_' + 'PS.pdf', ...)`

Comment: It works, all PDFs are created, but they all have the same content as the last row of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Well yeah, you're using `codigo` to fill your canvas, but as I said, `codigo` does not change between the iterations, you need to use the data you parsed into the lists `codigos, clients, etc`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I got the result I wanted.